# How to get a web client handling forms to send page ID info to server without client side scripting

Tags: html, c, linux, forms, fastcgi

I'm writing an application which will run on a microcontroller (arduino or Raspberry Zero) with wifi and a web server which will be configurable by a web browser without any client side scripts.  This will use a string of HTML forms for the purpose of creating a number of small files on the microcontroller which will be interpreted by the microcontroller to perform its tasks.
I'm writing it initially on a Slackware Linux system but when it gets close to completion, will move it all to a Raspberry Pi running a customised version of Ubuntu Linux for final tuning.
I'm using lighttpd with mod_fastcgi and libfcgi and I am writing forms handler software in C.
Now, ideally, the responses returned to the server by each form would be processed by its individual handler daemon started by mod_fcgi, however I have not been able to figure out how to configure fastcgi to load more than one handler daemon. My fcgi.conf file is pointed at by a link later in this missive.

I could live with this restriction but another problem arises.  In using just one handler, the action="handlerProgram"  field at the top of every form has to point at that one handler, each form is unique and must be handled differently so how do I tell the formsHandler program which form is being handled? I need to be able to embed another label into each HTML form somewhere so that the web client will send this back to the server which will pass its value to the forms handler via the environment - or some such mechanism. Any clues on how to do this? Pleaase?
Peter.
PS.  Here's a link to the related config and html data. [HTML Problem](http://pastebin.com/DgUQUc6G)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe one of these solutions may help :

1. In the html code, add informations about the form to handle after the handler program name in the action tag, like :

   action="/cgi-bin/handlerProgram/id/of/form/to/handle"

In your CGI handlerProgram you'll have the `PATH_INFO` environment variable valued to "/id/of/form/to/handle". Use it to know what form to handle.

2. In the html code add a hidden input field to your form like :

   <input type="hidden" id="form_to_hanlde" value="form_id"/>

Just use the `form_to_handle` field's value in you handlerProgram to know what form to handle.

Comment: Sorry, Joe.  when I use ptr = getenv("PATH_INFO");, ptr is a NULL.

Some of the docs say that ???_REFERER (I can't remember the start of that variable name offhand) should contain the contents of the ACTION field at the end of a complete URL but I get only an IP and port numbers.

Comment: Joe, I've just had a closer look at your comment and finally got through my thick head that you're saying that I have to add the info I want sent to the end of the name of my handler. OK, I'll try that after I've had some sleep and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Joe Hect Posted an answer which completely solves this question.
The information which needed to be sent for the form called 'index.htm' is the name of the form. I used the action field "ACTION=/formsHandler.fcgi/index.htm" and below is the contents of the environment returned as reported by echo.fcgi (renamed to formsHandler.fcgi to avoid having to change anything else in my config.). If you can decipher the listing after this page has scrambled it, you will see that the required information is now present in a number of places, including PATH_INFO as suggested.   Thank you, Joe.
Now all I have to do is figure out how to vote for you properly.

```
{
Request number 1
CONTENT_LENGTH: 37
DOCUMENT_ROOT: /home/lighttpd/htdocs
GATEWAY_INTERFACE: CGI/1.1
HTTP_ACCEPT: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING: gzip, deflate
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE: en-AU
HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL: no-cache
HTTP_CONNECTION: Keep-Alive
HTTP_HOST: 192.168.0.16:6666
HTTP_PRAGMA: 
HTTP_RANGE: 
HTTP_REFERER: http://192.168.0.16:6666/
HTTP_TE: 
HTTP_USER_AGENT: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR: 
PATH: 
PATH_INFO: /index.htm
PATH_TRANSLATED: /home/lighttpd/htdocs/index.htm
QUERY_STRING: 
CONTENT_LENGTH: 37
CONTENT: 
REMOTE_ADDR: 192.168.0.19
REMOTE_HOST: 
REMOTE_PORT: 54159
REQUEST_METHOD: POST
REQUEST_ACTION: 
ACTION: 
REQUEST_URI: /formsHandler.fcgi/index.htm
REDIRECT_URI: 
SCRIPT_FILENAME: /home/lighttpd/htdocs/formsHandler.fcgi
SCRIPT_NAME: /formsHandler.fcgi
SERVER_ADDR: 192.168.0.16
SERVER_ADMIN: 
SERVER_NAME: 192.168.0.16
SERVER_PORT: 6666
SERVER_PROTOCOL: HTTP/1.1
SERVER_SIGNATURE: 
SERVER_SOFTWARE: lighttpd/1.4.41
}
```